# RSpec: Testing Mailgun Email Receiving and Parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

So I am using Mailgun to receive and parse emails from users, and make posts in the system off the back of these. I am interested in how to use RSpec to test this - should I just send emails to my Mailgun address using standard Rails mailers or is there a cleverer way of doing things?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Mailgun, but you may want to check out the [email_spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec). It's very helpful for testing email sending.